# Blocked URL in Bing still showing up in search results

Tags: url, content, bing, block

I am trying to block a URL from showing up in search results.  I am the webmaster for the site, and the content has been deleted.

- I used the "block URL" link 2 days ago and the URL is still showing up in the Bing search results.
- I used the content removal tool last night and the status is showing "completed" and once again the link is still showing up.

How do I get the URL removed from Bing ASAP?

Comment: You're going to have to wait for the search engines to clear up their cache.  In the mean time, what about using a redirect to a different page?